# Not showing error massage on Mac but works perfectly on windows

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

Update: All the function is working properly now. It is doing all the necessary validation but Alertmassage (for example: ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "alertMessage", "alert('SSN already exists, record is updated.!')", true);) is not showing on the screen. 
It works perfectly on windows but not showing on Mac.

```
protected void BtnBtnInsert_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    MySqlCommand cmd;
    string str;

    MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(ConString);

    int Status = 0;
    con.Open();

    String UpdateQuery;
    String SSN;

    SSN = TxtBxSSSN.Text.ToString().Trim();

    if (CheckValidSSNBeforeUpdate(SSN) == "1")
    {
        ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "alertMessage", "alert('SSN already exists, record is updated.!')", true);
    }
    else
    {
        InsertNewEmployee();  
    }

    con.Close();
} 

public void InsertNewEmployee()
{
    String SSN, SFName, MName, LName, DOB, Address;

    SSN = TxtBxSSSN.Text.ToString().Trim();
    SFName = lblSFanme.Text.ToString().Trim();
    MName = lblMName.Text.ToString().Trim();
    LName = lblLName.Text.ToString().Trim();
    DOB = lblDOB.Text.ToString().Trim();
    Address = lblAddress.Text.ToString().Trim();

    String SSN1 = new String(SSN.Where(x => Char.IsDigit(x)).ToArray());

    String Tmpe = "SSN : " + SSN + " , SFName : " + SFName + " , MName : " + MName + " , LName : " + LName + " , DOB : " + DOB + " , Address : " + Address;

    if (SSN.Length == 0 || SFName.Length == 0 || MName.Length == 0 || LName.Length == 0 || DOB.Length == 0 || Address.Length == 0)
    {
        ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "alertMessage", "alert('Please enter values in all the fields. All fields are mandatory')", true);
    }
    else
    {
        if (SSN1.Length != 9)
        {
            ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "alertMessage", "alert('Invalid SSN, It must be of 9 digits')", true);
        }
        else
        {
            InsertNewEmployeeRecord();
        }
    }
}

public void InsertNewEmployeeRecord()
{
    String SSN, SFName, MName, LName, DOB, Address;

    SSN = TxtBxSSSN.Text.ToString().Trim();
    SFName = lblSFanme.Text.ToString().Trim();
    MName = lblMName.Text.ToString().Trim();
    LName = lblLName.Text.ToString().Trim();
    DOB = lblDOB.Text.ToString().Trim();
    Address = lblAddress.Text.ToString().Trim();

    MySqlCommand cmd;
    string str;

    MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(ConString);

    int Status = 0;
    con.Open();

    String InsertQuery;

    InsertQuery = "Insert Into Employee VALUES ('"+SSN+ "','"+DOB+"','"+SFName+"','"+MName+"','"+LName+"','"+Address+"')";

    cmd = new MySqlCommand(InsertQuery, con);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    con.Close();

    ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "alertMessage", "alert('Record inserted successfully.!')", true);
}
```

Comment: Do this: delete `'"+SSN+ "',` from your insert statemet and run your code. If it sends you an error message, it means it is working as coded.

Comment: Put a breakpoint in `InsertNewEmployeeRecord`. Do you get there?

Comment: @AntonioVenerosoContreras it doesn't send and error message.

Comment: *Principle of Least Surprise* - you should **not** call it `UpdateQuery`, when the code actually **inserts** a row (does not update at all) ..... this is just plain confusing to anyone looking at the code later on....

Comment: Also: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection - check out [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/)

Comment: Is it event getting into `BtnBtnInsert_Click`? How do you wire up that click handler? Keep adding breakpoints and stepping through your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the 'InsertNewEmployeeRecord' method you have the following:

```
String UpdateQuery;

InsertQuery = "Insert Into Employee VALUES ('"+SSN+ "','"+DOB+"','"+SFName+"','"+MName+"','"+LName+"','"+Address+"')";

cmd = new MySqlCommand(UpdateQuery, con);
```

You are declaring UpdateQuery, then you asign value to InsertQuery and then you execute the UpdateQuery, which is null.

So you need to use:

```
 cmd = new MySqlCommand(InsertQuery, con);
```

Comment: Thank you Insert command is working. But it is not showing any alert